# What is a word for "uncomfortable situation"?

Tags: synonyms, american-english

Pretty straight forward. Looking for a word that means uncomfortable situation but in a positive connotation, not like danger.

Comment: Dentist's chair.

Comment: @HotLicks Quite possibly the _gynecological examination chair_ is more awkward?

Comment: So it's probably the wrong moment to suggest **tight spot**.

Comment: So you're suffering but you're happy about it? It's either masochism, or Harry Potter-like ambivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Contretemps? https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/contretemps I assume you mean a *minor* incident, since it can't very well be positive to describe something as uncomfortable!

Answer (score 0):

"Awkward situation" https://www.dictionary.com/browse/awkward (`Hard to deal with; difficult`)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **Predicament**?

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/predicament

an unpleasantly difficult, perplexing, or dangerous situation.